# UITabbarController's "Done" button hidden behind UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm building a project using Xcode 4.2 and I'm also using the Storyboard. So basically, I have a UINavigationcontroller which is my initial view, connected to my "Main Menu" view. Inside my "Main Menu" I have a button that is linked to  a  tabbar controller, which has like 20  tabs. Therefore, a "More" button appears and when the "more" button is clicked an "edit" button appears. Everything works fine, but the only problem I have is that once I click edit, the configure page slides up and the "done" button is hidden behind the Navigation bar. Anyway I can the configure page slide up infront of the Navigation bar ?

Also, I used the Xcode 4.2's new feature. Where you can "Embed in NavigationController" and "Embed in TabbarController" under the Editor Toolbar. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `UITabBarController` should only ever be the root view controller of your window. Placing a `UITabBarController` inside another container view controller, like `UINavigationController`, can lead to undefined behavior.

From the [`UITabBarController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the
>   UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that
>   is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar
>   interface, you must install this view as the root of your window.
>   Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be
>   installed as a child of another view controller.

Comment: Do you have any solutions on how I would go about accomplishing this ?

Comment: Basically if you ever push to a view that is a `UITabBarController`, you're doing it wrong. The `UITabBarController` should be the first controller that is displayed at app launch.