# Making the Back button UINavigationController be active

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin

I'm trying to get a back button in my ios app to be active but it just appears without being clickable.
In this iOS app I'm working on, I have a TabBarController from where clicks can open further UIViewControllers. However, when I open the UIViewController, I see the NavigationItems I created, but with Back being not enabled. 
I'm going for an experience similar to iTunes Music (where you have a back button after loading the full UIViewController).
[image: Notice the back button faintly appearing]

[image: As compared to it working correctly in iTunes music.]

Comment: Oh, the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555281/uitabbarcontrollers-done-button-hidden-behind-uinavigationcontroller?rq=1 is helpful. Will report back

Answer (score 0):

OK, as it turns out, the link ([UITabbarController's "Done" button hidden behind UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555281/uitabbarcontrollers-done-button-hidden-behind-uinavigationcontroller?rq=1)) did help, it said:

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

At the time of setting the rootviewcontroller, I had:

```
window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new TabScreen());//TabScreen is a subclass of UITabBarController
```

I went ahead and did this:

```
window.RootViewController = new TabScreen();
```

And that led me out of the darkness.